# Label of a Disk in Prolog/Epilog

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, labeled

How do I label a disk when the disk is used in a `Prolog` or `Epilog` of a plot, such as:

```
PolarPlot[{\[Theta], Sqrt[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 3 \[Pi] + 0.1}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Blue, 
   Disk[{(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], (3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*
      Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3], Orange, 
   Disk[{Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], 
     Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3]}]
```

Which generates:
[image]

And I would like to add different labels to the individual disks, such as if generated by:

```
Labeled[Graphics@
  Disk[{(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], (3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*
     Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3], "Parampara", {{Right, Center}}, 
 RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Apparently, `Labeled` cannot be used as MA is complaining about graphics primitives, and I could not find a way to do this. There might be a way with `Show`, but I am already using the plot in a show so that the whole thing will get way too complicated.

Comment: Maybe [**Text**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) would be helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
PolarPlot[{\[Theta], Sqrt[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 3 \[Pi] + 0.1}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Blue, 
   Disk[{(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], (3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*
      Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3], 
   Text[Style["1", White, Bold, 
     12], {(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], (3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*
      Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}], Orange, 
   Disk[{Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], 
     Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3], 
   Text[Style["2", White, Bold, 
     12], {Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], 
     Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}]}]
```

Maybe `Text` can help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
PolarPlot[{\[Theta], Sqrt[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 3 \[Pi] + 0.1}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "PastelColor"}, ImageSize -> 800,
 Prolog -> {{Blue, 
    Disk[{(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], (3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*
       Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3], 
    Text[Style["Parampara", 18, Bold, Blue, 
      FontFamily -> "Manjari"], {-8.9, -0.9}, Automatic, {0, 1}], 
    Black, Line[{{-8.8, -2.1}, {-8.8, 0.4}}]}, {Orange, 
    Disk[{Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], 
      Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 0.3], 
    Text[Style["Pratistha", 18, Bold, Orange, 
      FontFamily -> "Manjari"], {-2.4, -0.2}, Automatic, {0, 1}], 
    Black, Line[{{-2.3, -1.2}, {-2.3, 0.8}}]}},
 
 Epilog -> {Text[
    Style["1", 18, Bold, White, 
     FontFamily -> "Waree"], {(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*
      Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], (3 \[Pi] + 0.1)*Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 
    Automatic, {1, 0}],
   Text[Style["2", 18, White, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Waree"], {Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*
      Cos[3 \[Pi] + 0.1], Sqrt[(3 \[Pi] + 0.1)]*Sin[3 \[Pi] + 0.1]}, 
    Automatic, {1, 0}] }
 ]
```

[image]